# Win-Acme / Let's encrypt DNS txt validation?

Tags: iis, lets-encrypt

How do I do the DNS txt record validation? There are simply no tutorial or any info whatsoever about it.
I need to bypass regular validation mechanism cause it uses Amazon which is banned here. How do I generate a TXT record to add to GoDaddy? I use Win-Acme, I'm on IIS.
There is [this link](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) talking about a token but of course and as usual, there is no reference or link to any tool, nor there is info on how to generate a token.

Comment: I created a cert today like:
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email me@domain.at --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d *.domain.at

Comment: Where can I find certbot? There is no certbot on Win-Acme / Windows...

Comment: Its an "own" client app for generating certs with acme - https://github.com/certbot/certbot/releases/download/v1.10.1/certbot-beta-installer-win32.exe

Comment: see also: https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions

Comment: Win acme seems to have a manual DNS plugin, which shows the record to create: https://www.win-acme.com/reference/plugins/validation/dns/manual.

Comment: https://www.win-acme.com/reference/plugins/validation/dns/manual this is not a solution and work only on unattended certs.

Comment: @Berndinox https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions does not contain anything for IIS